# What is the minimum length of time/cycles a System Verilog wait() statement will wait?

Tags: system-verilog, systemc

I have a SystemVerilog task I am trying to port to SystemC. The body of the task simply waits on a boolean expression and then pushes onto a queue. The SystemC wait mechanism doesn't work quite the same way though, it will only wait on time or events.

So I'm wondering what is the minimum length of cycles/time that SystemVerilog wait() will wait before re-testing the boolean expression. In other words, how often or what drives re-testing of boolean expressions in SV wait()?

If the answer is simply once every cycle, which I hope and expect but can not confirm, then the solution is easy.

Here is the code, with some things renamed and simplified to make more sense out of context:

```
    virtual task put(input cls_item item);
        wait (queuecount < queuemax);
        push_back(item);
    endtask
```

Comment: Can you post the code in question? SystemVerilog has a concept of cycles but they are not related to wait()

Answer (score 3):

From the LRM:

> ### 9.4.3 Level-sensitive event control
>
> The execution of a procedural statement can also be delayed until a condition becomes true. This is accomplished
>   using the wait statement, which is a special form of event control. The nature of the wait statement is
>   level-sensitive, as opposed to basic event control (specified by the @ character), which is edge-sensitive.
>
> The wait statement shall evaluate a condition; and, if it is false, the procedural statements following the wait
>   statement shall remain blocked until that condition becomes true before continuing.

Basically, you can think of `wait(<boolean expression>)` as checking the expression continuously.  Once the expression is true the wait will unblock and the execution of the sequential code will continue.

If the expression is true when the `wait()` is first encountered, it will not wait at all.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree you can think of `wait(expression)` as always checking the condition expression continuously. That's thought for the designer, but a computer program can not be designed at that way or it wastes CPU time in the condition checking loop.

In `SystemVerilog`, its compiler might model the boolean expression as an event.
When the execution runs to `wait()` and condition is false, the simulation kernel suspend the current thread and execute others. In the simulation, every time `queuecount` or `queuemax` has been changed, the condition is re-computed using `<` operator. Once the condition is satisfied, the event is triggered and then the waiting thread is re-schedule and prepared to resume its execution.

In `SystemC`, because it's `C/C++` world plus an event driven hardware modeling library, that's the natural of `C/C++` you write a function like `function(<condition expression>)`. However, after `C/C++` compilation like `GCC`, actually the program will first evaluate the `<condition expression>` then pass as the argument to the function. It is the software way. Such that, in `wait()` function, it can only see `true` or `false` or 0/1, it does know about what you are waiting for. It does not make any sense for the real intent of `wait()` in hardware modeling. Therefore, the `wait()` can only accepts `event` argument in SystemC. For example,

```
wait (event);       // waiting for the event
wait (a_signal);    // signal interface has value_changed_event, posedge_event, negedge_event
wait (10, SC_NS);   // simulation time is also an event in SC kernel
```

If you would like to model the same condition for `wait()` like SystemVerilog, you have to manually write the detail of events. Following is a proof of concept pseudo code, you can find examples from SystemC or sc_fifo class.

```
    sc_event           waiting_event;

    void put( ... ) {
        while (!(queuecount < queuemax))
            wait( waiting_event);
        push_back(...);
    }

    void get( ... ) {
        ...
        notify_queue_available();
    }

    void notify_queue_available() {
        if (queuecount < queuemax)
            waiting_event.notify();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. One thing I overlooked previously is that in SV this kind of wait() is blocking. In other words, the task (or thread in more SystemC/C terms) that calls this task won't regain control until the wait is finished. This means I could implement an equivalent in SystemC with a kind of blocking spinlock. Something like: while (!(queuecount < queuemax) sleep(1000); Do you agree, or do I misunderstand the nature of SV wait()?

Comment: No, sleep doesn't give control to other threads or processes in SYstemC. It will cause infinite loop because those two variables wont be changed.